# Adding conditional statements as Math expression to custom text fields in views

Tags: views, entities

I have created views in which i have added custom text and Math expression.
I displayed view in table format
I created one Math expression which is noticed below:

```
[Field 1] - [Field 2]
```

I have displayed this expression into another custom field in views.

Now i want to add some condition statements. 
That is

```
If [expression] >= 0
 'display something'
else
 'other texts'
```

Is it possible to add conditional statement in Math expression views?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can override any of the output you have from views with a template override.

Goto your Views > Display

on the right hand side in the box labelled 'other'

> click on information next to 'theme'

This will give you a list of template pages you can use to over write the section you need.  A little trial and error maybe needed at first until you get used to what your being presented.

> on the left hand side of the page suggested you have a link to the code you need to use.  Copy that code and paste it into the file name your targetting ( ie views-view-field--default.tpl.php ) and add in the theme/templates  folder your using.
>
> from here on you can manipulate the code how you want using php

Hope this makes sense, as I wrote it real quick :)

Comment: Ya i know this. But if i follow your answer, then i need to create new tpl file for every views. I don't need to do this.

Comment: you could target for the custom field instead.  and reuse that for each view.  would that solve your problem.

Comment: I have added custom field only. I want to change the content of field based on another field. It is possible in views